# Setting an auto increment value

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

If I have schemas SCHEMA1 with tables tbl_one and tbl_two, SCHEMA2 with table tbl_tree,
how to use in PostgreSQL command `setval()`:

```
SELECT SETVAL('SCHEMA1.tbl_one_id_seq', 234) FROM SCHEMA1.tbl_one;
SELECT SETVAL('SCHEMA1.tbl_two_id_seq', 345) FROM SCHEMA1.tbl_two;
SELECT SETVAL('SCHEMA2.tbl_tree_id_seq', 456) FROM SCHEMA2.tbl_tree;
```

These don't work.

Comment: "*these don't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `FROM` clause. Just:

```
SELECT SETVAL('SCHEMA1.tbl_one_id_seq', 234);
```

In future, when you say "it doesn't work" you should be specific about what error message you get *exactly*.

Possibly your schema is case-perserved? If so, you want:

```
SELECT SETVAL('"SCHEMA1"."tbl_one_id_seq"', 234);
```

Note the quotes on the identifier to prevent case-folding.

Comment: The schema-qualification for sequences was introduced later, IIRC with PG-9.0 (maybe the OP is still using <= pg8.4 ? )

Answer (score 2):

Try `ALTER SEQUENCE SCHEMA1.tbl_one_id_seq RESTART WITH 234` and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Note the lower case spelling of `'schema1.tbl_one_id_seq'`. Unless you double-quoted names when creating objects, you need to lower case the name here.

```
SELECT setval('schema1.tbl_one_id_seq', max(id))
FROM   SCHEMA1.tbl_one    -- case irrelevant while not double-quoted
```

Fetching the maximum `id`, btw - else you wouldn't need to select from the table.